# structtype add method to add arraytype

Tags: pyspark, struct

structtype has a method call add. i see example to use

```
schema = Structype()
schema.add('testing',string)
schema.add('testing2',string)
```

how can I add Structype and array type in the schema , using add()?

Comment: anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it as below -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType()
schema.add('testing',StringType())
schema.add('testing2',StringType())
```

Sample example to create a dataframe using this `schema` -

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(1,2), (3,4)],schema=schema)
df.show()

+-------+--------+
|testing|testing2|
+-------+--------+
|      1|       2|
|      3|       4|
+-------+--------+
```